# State not updating when "Save" is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, react-hooks

I'm trying to update a state when I press "Save" after set a bunch of items in the TransferList component made by Material-UI. The problem is, when I click "Save", it doesn't update. If I click again or make any interaction with the component, it updates.

I created a code on Code SandBox so you don't have to figure out what I'm saying. The code is already working and I put a list below with nine items explaining exactly what my problem is. Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/question-about-hook-state-f3jtl

I suspect useEffect could be the solution. I can't find out how to trigger it just when I click on "Save" to avoid performance issues. You might ask "why are you updating the "right" state to have the effort of updating "data.items" just right after? Why not updating "data.items". Well, Material-UI code are very bound and changing it seemed terrifying.

Comment: Please don't use words like "it": be explicit about what is, and what is not, getting updated. The TransferList component, as a React component, already updated its state when you selected things (because that's the only way for it to render correctly), so presumably when you say "it doesn't update" you mean some other component, like a parent, or the top level App. Be specific in your post. Also, while links to codepen/jsbin/etc are useful, remember that questions should contain all the relevant information [in the post](/help/how-to-ask) because external links can disappear.

Comment: Again, I shared a link explaining exactly what my problem is. I looked the link again after reading your answer to confirm it's understandable and I think it is.

Comment: I'll consider your sugestions, indeed. What doesn't update is the "data" state.

Comment: Please do the relevant code to the question itself and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: While you guys complain there's no code here, others complain about big questions. I can't get both sides satisfied. Material-UI's TransferList component is big. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions. I'll be waiting for anyone to help.

Comment: Except you can. You first describe the problem, then you show the relevant [mcve] code, then you explain where you've been doing your own debugging. No matter how compex your app, you can _always_ reduce it to a handful of MCVE code because almost nothing about your app reflects on your current problem, so you can cut it out. Plus, that exercise almost always forces you into looking at the code in a way that lets you automatically spot the problem yourself. It's one of the most powerful pieces of debug advice/policy on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working well, but if you want to print right state in event, change it to:

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    setData(prevState => {
      let newState = { ...prevState, items: right };
      console.log("handleClick", newState);

      return newState;
    });

    //  console.log("handleClick", data);
    //  console.log("right", right);
  };
```

Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater.

here fixed example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/question-about-hook-state-sb0jo

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going to search for the "prevState" you used as parameter in setData with newState. It's working. Thanks again.

Comment: What if the "Save" button is a json sender? It seems I need to send the json data inside the setData method using your approach, otherwise I will send the outdated data. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, read more https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: Read the "note" section in article